# Chi square goodness-of-fit test for Uniform distribution using Matlab

Tags: statistics, matlab

I need to test random numbers generators in 1, 2 and 3 dimensions. Criteria of test is that generated numbers are from uniform distribution. **I am doing this using Matlab**. I'm told to use Chi-2 test statistic $$\chi^2=\sum^B_{i=1}\frac{(expected(i)-observed(i))^2}{expected(i)}$$
where $B$ is number of bins, $expected(i)=\frac{N}{B}$ for all $i$ is expected number of elements in $i_{th}$ bin and $N$ is number of generated numbers.

What I have done is that I generated

- $N\times 1$ matrix of random numbers for $1D$
- $N\times 2$ matrix of random numbers for $2D$
- $N\times 3$ matrix of random numbers for $3D$

Then, I set a number of bins (B) for each component of matrix elements and I created zero matrices of sizes

- $1\times B$ for $1D$
- $B\times B$ for $2D$
- $B\times B\times B$ for $3D$

and, using loops, I counted how many generated numbers are in which bin and those were, actually, values $observed(i)$.
At this point I am able to calculate $\chi^2$ test statistic for all 3 dimensions.

I know how to read $\chi^2$ table but I don't know how to check significance using Matlab. I'm also not sure about degrees of freedom, but I think it's $B-1$ for $1D$, $BB-1$ for $2D$ and $BBB-1$ for $3D$ since we don't have to estimate any parameter for uniform distribution. I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That all sounds right; looks like you're almost done. All you need to do now is call `chi2cdf(x,v,'upper')` where $x$ is your $\chi^2$ test statistic and $v$ is your degrees of freedom; this will output the P-value for the test.

Comment: Thank you!
While I was waiting for some help here, I found that p-value is **1-chi2cdf(x,v)**. Now I am a bit confused.

Can you tell me when we use **chi2gof**?

Comment: Yes, `1-chi2cdf(x,v)` is the same as `chi2cdf(x,v,'upper')`, although the former is more prone to floating-point roundoff error and hence may give a less accurate answer if the P-value is extremely small. 

The way you have solved this problem, you have calculated the $\chi^2$ test statistic manually. `chi2gof` is a function which can do this for you; if you pass it the appropriate options, it should give you the same answer as before.

Comment: I wrote a code but I think it doesn't work correctly. When I generate numbers from uniform distribution, it says that distribution of uniformly distributed numbers is consistent with uniform, which is expected. But it also happens when I generate numbers from normal distribution. Here is the code on google drive (https://docs.google.com/document/d/19MIP4aV5QPDZZGSG2i6NEEEq82QY_Nn9xfoTc5gqAuI/edit?usp=sharing). I would appreciate if you would check it. You are also allowed to comment it.

Comment: All right, I've spotted a bug and commented on it.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it. Maybe it's not still correct. I put a code for numbers generated from N(0,1) distribution and I tested it for uniform distribution. For 1D I got that it's not consistent with uniform distribution, but for 2D and 3D I got that it is.

Comment: There was another bug; I commented on it. By the way, do you receive a notification when I add a comment to the document?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting notifications. I saw another comment. Thanks. Wow, I'm an expert for making errors :) Thank you. I will change it now. I'll tell you results! :)

Comment: I corrected it on drive. If you have time, please check it one more time. It seems it works now.

Answer (score 7):

Just to expend on it and give the all the code.

## Setting parameters

```
N=100; % sample size
a=0; % lower boundary
b=1; % higher boundary
```

Sample N uniformly distributed values between a and b. And in the second line add some bais to make it not uniform if you want to test the code.

```
x=unifrnd(a,b,N,1);
%x(x<.9) = rand(sum(x<.9),1);
```

## Using [`chi2gof`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html)

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996380/uniform-distribution-fitting-in-matlab), with [`chi2gof`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html), you can't use the 'cdf of the hypothesized distribution' and need to specified the bins, the edges and the expected values.

```
nbins = 10; % number of bin
edges = linspace(a,b,nbins+1); % edges of the bins
E = N/nbins*ones(nbins,1); % expected value (equal for uniform dist)

[h,p,stats] = chi2gof(x,'Expected',E,'Edges',edges)
```

## Using [`chi2cdf`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2cdf.html)

With this function you need to supply the chi-squared test statistic, $\displaystyle \chi ^{2}$ which can be computed with the function `histogramm`:

```
h = histogram(x,edges);
chi = sum((h.Values - N/nbins).^2 / (N/nbins));
k = nbins-1; % degree of freedom
chi2cdf(chi, k)
```

Note, that if you don't use the edges to compute the number of value per bins, `histogramm` will choose them from the lower value to the highest and therefore the final score will be different than with `chi2gof`

## Quick Theory recall

Just to recall how to interpret the final value, few definition:

- The [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) ($H_0$) is that the data `x` *are* coming from a uniform distribution.
- [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) is testing if you can safely *reject* the null hypothesis, i.e. "Can I say that `x` is not a coming from a uniform distribution ? "
- Pearson's cumulative test statistic $\displaystyle \chi ^{2}$ is a measure of the *error* between observations and expected value
  $$\displaystyle \chi ^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$$
- [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is the distribution that the Pearson's cumulative test statistic $\displaystyle \chi ^{2}$ would follow according $H_0$ (i.e. if the observation are coming from a uniform distribution)
- The [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) is the probability of obtaining a worst result than what was observation, *when the null hypothesis is true*. That is, the probability that, if we randomly draw a dataset `y` in a uniform distribution, the error (or Pearson's cumulative test) will be equal of *higher* than the actual observation `x` (=worst case).
- So, we can reject $H_0$ if `p` is lower than a [significant level $\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance). That is, for small value of `p`, we can safely say that `x` is *not* coming from a uniform distribution.